# What are the benefits, if i use rails view form template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Example, i made a form like this

```
<form name="register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><h3>User check</h3></p>
  <p>admin ID: <input type="text" name="userid"></p>
  <p>admin Pass: <input type="password" name="password"></p>

  <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Submit"></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

and my manager wants to change this form to rails form template like this,

```
<%= form_for(:model) do |form| %>
<p>
    <%=form.label :input%>
    <%=form.text_field :input, :placeholder => 'Enter text here...'%>
</p>

<%end%>
```

My question is, it works fine with html based front code. Why do i have to change this to rails code? I just want to keep my front-end code...I don't know why i have to change this :(. Also, I'm new on Ruby on Rails. That is the main reason. I dont' want to change the existing code, if it is working.

I really hate this job. I have to translate all the attributes to the rails code and that makes me really exhausted  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Form builders are here to help

Form helpers are supposed to make your life simpler. They are quicker to write than their pure html alternative, provided you don't write pure html first.

They also provide a lot of easy implementations for difficult integration pieces, like :

- displaying a date selection select group
- mirroring the fact that a check box has been unchecked in POST params
- automatically adding multipart param on form if you add a file input (not actually difficult to achieve, but easy to forget)
- ... and many more

## Further development

All of this is about comfort, and you may think you could avoid it if you already have a perfectly working pure html implementation.

But what happen if someone later has to add a date select input in your form ? She will have to use the rails helper, since it saves a lot of time in controller part to set date in database. But she won't be able to leverage form builder, since you haven't used it.

Now, she has to choose between using a non builder`date_select` tag mixed in pure html or ... to rewrite your form completely. As you may realize, mixing different styles is generally considered ugly, and we don't like ugly in ruby.

## Security

Form tag helpers also provide an important security measure : [CSRF protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). Every time you use a rails helper to create a `<form>` tag, it automatically adds an hidden input containing a secret key. That key has to be posted with form data to prove request originated from current website.

If you use plain html forms, you won't have this security. You could of course add the token manually using the correct method, but this would again be more time wasting than simply using form helpers.

## Bottom line

The main problem is that you write pure html before using rails helpers - that is what is wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* benefits of using Rails form helpers are:

- Consistent naming of input elements names and ids
- i18n support for labels
- generated URL with form_for is less error prone
- Better handling of checkboxes
- Nice helpers like `options_for_select`
- Less typing

That last ones might be my favourite: *less typing*.